# Perl 6 List Concatenation without Slip?

Tags: concatenation, raku

In Perl the `,` operator can be used to concatenate Lists; however, Perl 6 does not flatten Lists in this context resulting in a List of two Lists. Concatenating the Lists requires using `|`, the slip operator.

```
my @a = <a b c>;
my @b = <d e f>;
my @ab = |@a, |@b;
```

Is there any shorthand for this operation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the "flat" sub for this:

```
my @a  = <a b c>;
my @b  = <d e f>;
my @ab = flat @a, @b;
say @ab.perl; #> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
my @abf = (@a, @b).flat;
say @abf.perl; #> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Comment: or `my @ab = (@a, @b).flat;`

Comment: This should probably point out that it will remove multiple layers if the values aren't scalars. `my \list = (1,2,(3,4,(5,6))); say flat list` => `(1 2 3 4 5 6)` but using `|( )` only flatten individual parts  `my \list = (1,2,|( (3,4,(5,6)) )); say list` => `(1 2 3 4 (5 6))`